# Create floppy disk image with FreeBSD

Tags: unix, images, freebsd, floppy

So I don't have a usb floppy drive for my laptop, but oddly enough, I find myself wishing I did now.  I do have an old machine with a floppy drive running FreeBSD 8.2, so I thought I might just use it instead.  On my laptop I have VirtualBox and I want to load MSDOS 6.22 as a host OS so that I can play some old flight-sim games I used to enjoy.

In VirtualBox I added a floppy controller, and the only type option is I82078.  It looks like I can load *.img files as floppy images and that will emulate a floppy drive.

How can I create floppy disk images on the FreeBSD machine so that I can copy them to my laptop and then have VirtualBox read them?  Are there any specific tools I should be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was so much easier than I thought:

```
 dd if=/dev/fd0 of=/home/msdos_disk1.img  
 dd if=/dev/fd0 of=/home/msdos_disk2.img
 dd if=/dev/fd0 of=/home/msdos_disk3.img
```

and VirtualBox can handle them just like that.